# tmux status bar showing the terminal's available width and height in pixels

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux, stty

It would be nice if tmux could display the width and height of a current window within its status bar.
I personally use :resize-window -x -y quite a lot, cause I connect from a computer to a second screen that is bigger and I dont want the smaller one to resize it)
But sometimes I dont know the dimensions of the screen, and I have to go through stty -a and set each of the Windows of a Session accordingly.

So It would be of great deal , have that information in the status bar, for that I have created a little script that does.

```
getTerminalRows

#!/bin/bash

stty -a | grep rows | awk '{print $7}' | tr -d ';'
```

(I have done the same with columns)

Now In my `.tmux.conf` I have appended the following

```
set -g status-left '#(/mypath/to/getTerminalColumns) x #(/mypath/to/getTerminalRows) '
```

this part of the status bar shows empty.
So I have tried with the following.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s checkwinsize
echo $COLUMNS
```

This one doesn't even work by its own , not to say in the status bar.

Comment: (1) `stty` or `$COLUMNS` inside a tmux pane will show you the dimension(s) of the *pane*, not of the window. If a similar piece of code is run by a tmux *server* then it won't work because the server itself has no tty. By "the width and height of a current window" do you mean the values already set by `resize-window`? Or the dimensions of the tty of the *client*? Or what? Maybe you just want `window-size largest`. You can get the dimensions of the tty of the client with `set -g status-left '#{client_width} x #{client_height} '`. Is this what you want? (2) In pixels? (the title). Why?

Comment: Also see what `resize-window -A` does. *Maybe* this is what you want ultimately.

Comment: Thank you , both answers sorted my doubt

Comment: @freddie_ventura please either answer his questions so that he can answer or add a final answer yourself, don't leave the question at that very unclear comment.

Comment: Ok to be clear with my answer.
set -g status-left '#{client_width} x #{client_height} ' Is what I was looking for. But mainly because I needed to resize-window manually , but as I didnt know that resize-window -A (that parameter) existed , so I neither need the first , but I am going to use it as well as I think is a really valuable information.
Thank you very much